# Sitemap tree indentation visualization

Tags: javascript, html, css, sitemap

For a sitemap page I have the ordered text and the associated 'level' of how far the page is in the tree.

Right now we have the most simplistic indented look using CSS margins and we want it to look more funky.

Here is the sample code and a link to a test page:

HTML:

```
<div class='sitemapItem'>
  <a href="#">
    <div class='sitemapLevelX'>FOO</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sitemapLevelX{
    margin-left:Ypx;
}
```

Sample code can be found here:
http://jsfiddle.net/m77TR/1/

I include the following image to get an idea what I'm aiming for:

[image]

Is it possible to do relatively simply in CSS? Or do I need to sprinkle some javascript on top?

Answer (score 3):

You could simply achieve this structure  using a nested ul:

```
<ul>
    <li>level 1</li>
    <li>level 1</li>
    <li>level 1 with sub
        <ul>
            <li>level 2</li>
            <li>level 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This way you can easily define this kind of subtree structure in HTML. After this you can change the styling in CSS to fit your needs.

A demo for your desired layout can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/N4JH2/ and a tutorial on how to get this done here: http://www.csscody.com/css/css-sitemap-design-tutorial/594/

Comment: Ah, yes, the bullet points add some visual clues. But, the display logic and HTML content becomes more complicated. Prefer if the presentation is kept out of the content.

Comment: here's an example of the exact layout you're trying to achieve... but it uses the same ul structure as my demo... http://www.csscody.com/css/css-sitemap-design-tutorial/594/ what you can probably try if you really want to use divs with classes. is to write a javascript functions which converts these classes to the ul structure... But i don't think this is the best way to go. I think you should seriously consider using this kind of structure. As it is better structurized.

Comment: Thanks for the link. "Time to see the final result – voile!" not exactly convinced they got it to work...

Comment: They did ... their demos are just broken apparently. i just made a jsFiddle to show: http://jsfiddle.net/N4JH2/

Comment: If you are generating a sitemap then using a `ul` structure is the best approach as, amongst other things, it gives search engines a very clear idea of how your website (assuming this is for a website) is structured.

Answer (score -1):

The closest css property I can think of is 'quotes', which allows you to define different symbols for different levels of quotes.